# How to create a date range query using Mysql timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

just need a little help here I hope you can help me with my simple problem.

I have a table that consist of shops data. In my PHP page the user can register their shops.
And in registration the day that the user registered his/her account will be save in the database table and will format as a **TIMESTAMP**.

I have no problem with that. In my backend page there is a form for advance searching method. In my form, there is a **dropdown field** and beside it there is a **datepicker** that will format as **mm/dd/yyyy** so I have a 2 datepicker for that which is **from** and **to**.

*My problem is:*

I formatted the datepicker result using the **strtotime()** function in PHP. And I have a query like this.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shops
          WHERE status = '".$status."'
          AND registered BETWEEN ('".$from." AND ".$to."')";
```

*Sample output of query is:*

```
 SELECT * FROM shops WHERE status = 'P' AND registered BETWEEN ('1388505600' AND '1391097600');
```

Now I have a timestamp result for $from and $to. How can I filter it in mysql?

Ok that's all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should actually format a proper `YYYY-MM-DD` string format in PHP.

There basically is rarely ever a reason to work with UNIX timestamps in MySQL.

So do something like this for each of your datepicker to/from values:

```
$to_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y|', $datepicker_to);
$to = $to_datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$from_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y|', $datepicker_from);
$from = $from_datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

And then use them in your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shops
          WHERE status = '".$status."'
          AND registered BETWEEN ('".$from."' AND '".$to."')";
```

Note that I have used PHP `DateTime` class, which I would HIGHLY recommend as your go to tool for date manipulation in PHP (along with it's related classes like `DateInterval`, `DatePeriod`, `DateTimeZone`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks sir Mike for the very informative answer. I will try it now and study this code for my referrence. Thanks.

Comment: Sir I got an error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in`

Comment: @Jerielle It seems the creation of DateTime object did not work (though that should have thrown an Exception). Can you tell me what value you passes for `$datepicker_to` or `$datepicker_from` (whichever one you got error on)? Do you have a typo?

Comment: Ok, I passed my variables which is `$convert_from` and `$convert_to` to this `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Comment: So what values do they have?  Also note I changed my code a bit above to set time portion of DateTime object to `00:00:00` though this should make a difference in your error.

Comment: The values of my `$convert_to and $convert_from` is in format of `mm/dd/yyyy` and I used `strtotime()` function for this and it will create a timestamp. And the timestamp is the one that I passed in the `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Comment: Do I need to convert my date into timestamp before passing to `DateTime::createFromFormat`?

Comment: @Jerielle No. That method takes a string of the format specified.. There is no need to get unix timestamp at all during this process. Go straight from your string to DateTime object. Just realized you said your format is m/d/Y not d/m/Y as I originally showed in code example. My example has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes around the timestamps and you need to use FROM_UNIXTIME() if the column `registered` is not in UNIX time already.

Comment: This won't help at all in that there still needs to be a conversion between unix timestamp and MySQL datetime formats.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE status = '".$status."' AND registered BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(".$from.") AND FROM_UNIXTIME(".$to.")";
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
// $t is the value you got from strtotime()
$FormattedDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t)
```

Comment: You actually need `Y-m-d H:i:s` for MySQL compatibility.